# How can I Fix incompatibility between device and application on Google Play?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-sdk-tools

I've andorid appplication that has minSdkVersion 15 and targetSdkVersion 28 but when publish on Google Play it gives message "Your Device isn't compatible with this version" on Android 4.4.2 which shall have API 19 – 20 according to [Android version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history). Now what I do need to know is how to analyze the reason and how to approach to fix this situation.

My application works fine on debug and release editions on that Android 4.4.2 device

**Edit**:
I've found the FEATURE_CONNECTION_SERVICE is available only on API 21, How do I find the exact feature that is not work, is it a package I use inside my app or a permission tag, my manifest has theses permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
```

Comment: your manifest likely limits something

Comment: check with your manifest file. there will be uses features which is not available in your phone

Answer (score 0):

READ_PHONE_NUMBERS is only available in API 26.

You can find all the API levels here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission